# JavaSound API not available

Tags: java, javasound

I have started a new modular JavaFX project based on OpenJDK14 and OpenJFX14. This is a modular project with maven. I now have the problem that I would like to use the Java Sound API but cannot import any classes.

When I type (inside Netbeans): import javax. ... there is no code completion for the package javax.sound. I have another project, also based on OpenJDK14 and OpenJFX but does not use Maven or a modular design and there I can import the classes from the sound library.

I have to commit that I'm new to modular design and Maven, so maybe there is something I have to configure in my pom.xml or in the module-info.java to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your setup include the `java.desktop` module? That's the location of the `javax.sound.sampled` library.

Comment: No, I did not. As told, I'm new to modular design and was not aware that the sound API resides in another module.

I added java.desktop to my module-info.java and know I can import classes from the Sound API.

Thanks for the suggestion